# converting javascript function to python with comma operator

Tags: javascript, python

I have the following javascript code

```
var d = Math.random(),
   k = parseInt((1e3 * d)/2),
   s = d + ""
```

output of d : `0.6715250159864421`

Similarly, I have the python code that I was able to write up and as close to

```
d, k, s = random.random(), int((1e3*random.random()/2)), d + ''
```

The output are completely different.

```
0.8018834108596731
```

Am I not using the comma operator properly

PS: I understand output is going to be different, however I want to validate that my python code is correctly translated to the shown JS snippet.

Comment: The output is random. It's *supposed* to be different every time you run it, regardless of language. But your Python isn't an accurate translation, since you aren't using the `d` variable in the construction of `k`

Comment: I was under the impression perhaps the code translation is incorrect, want to validate that first, any feedback on that?

Comment: It's not, but you'll be getting different random results even if it was accurate.

Comment: They're pretty obviously different, aside from the fact that these are totally different random number generator algorithms, and even if they were the same, they'd need to be seeded to have any hope of giving you the same result. In JS, you make one call to `Math.random` and in Python you're making 2 calls to `random.random`. How could these possibly be the same, given that? You really don't need to use commas here--you can initialize the vars on three separate lines and used the cached value of `d`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Python code you're not using `d` when you calculate `k`, you're calculating a different random number.

In Python you can't concatenate strings with numbers. JS is using that to convert the number to a string, in Python you do that with the `str()` function.

The translation should be:

```
d = random.random()
k = int(1e3 * d) / 2
s = str(d)
```

In Python 3.8 you could use the "walrus" operator to assign to `d` in a one-liner

```
k, s = int(1e3 * (d := random.random())) / 2, str(d)
```

But this is confusing, so I don't recommend it.